# Why do I get "stack underflow" when executing sendTransaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, raw-transaction

I'm using geth to store data strings into Ropsten. All of them are 128 byte long strings (in fact they are all SHA512 hashes of data files).

I just call web3.eth.sendTransaction with the string I need to store in its "data" field, like this:

`web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: source, to:source, value:0, data: '0x' + imgHash})`

The transaction is created and uploaded to the blockchain. It works like a charm.

I'm also using "getTransaction" to read those strings from the blockchain, and it works perfectly, too.

Please note that I'm not using smart contracts at all.

The problem comes when I take a look at those transactions in ropsten.etherscan.io. The result of all of the transactions sent is "Error in Txn: Stack underflow", although as I mentioned, they're all correctly uploaded to the blockchain.

[image]

I'm not too worried, since everything works as I want it to, but I can't figure out why is this "stack underflow" error happening. It seems a bit weird to me that everytime I send a transaction it shows a "contract creation" in etherscan...

Can anyone please explain to me why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Sure: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf8120580ddbd1be1f0569302242bd0bce063c9cd

Comment: I just tried this exact line of code on the main network: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xc97f9547a1877b7b43c549a6d284cda511006d28a483610ac2e653788eb50806 Can you check what the value of the `source` variable is when you call `sendTransaction`? As far as I know, transactions to the 0x0 zero address are considered contract creation.

Comment: The `source` variable was ok, but I was missing a blank space after the `:`, looks like it wasn't working for that reason. Thank you so much, Jesse! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in your transaction it is setting "to" to null. Since transaction with receiver set to null are interpreted as contract creation, it tries to execute your data is it were a constructor for a contract.

Since you data is random, it will fail. Some of the bytes from you data are valid opcodes for the EVM, it tries to execute them and fail with the error message you are getting, and that stops the execution.

Make sure your "source" variable is not null, or undefined, or 0.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. For some reason `to:source` wasn't working, I had to put a blank space after the `:`, because source was correct. Thanks a lot! :)