# error occured Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, ethers.js, avalanche

### Intro

I am making my first ever smart contract. So please cut me some slack.
Basically, I am trying to make a staking contract in which I want the ability to deposit my USDC which should be done by using **stakeTokens()** function that I have defined in my contract.

> I successfully deployed my contract on Avalanche Fuji testnet using truffle.

#### Objective

I was trying to send 2 USDC from my *0x69e3E27BBA76B8789dB1E0AA0B816bF93570EFdf* wallet to my contract *0x0B4ae929F3181815bA8Bd9873ED31b4e75e21aFE* using the stakeTokens(2, _from, _to) function defined in my contract.
**More info, I have 1.9 AVAX and 7 USDC both testnet in my wallet.**

#### Error

Now when I tried to interact with the smart contract I had the following error:

```
error occured Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xea3a62f9426fcdcbb6e183dc24576e92695c6996fe8573b38614ad86ed4d8938",
  "blockNumber": 10313473,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 154456,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 25000000000,
  "from": "0x69e3e27bba76b8789db1e0aa0b816bf93570efdf",
  "gasUsed": 86686,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": "0x0b4ae929f3181815ba8bd9873ed31b4e75e21afe",
  "transactionHash": "0xdd74634fd8496adafa4b9d733e004d13fb4a9ebb746a327b8586e43e4b00bbc6",
  "transactionIndex": 2,
  "type": "0x0"
}
```

#### Receipt:

```
    blockHash: '0xea3a62f9426fcdcbb6e183dc24576e92695c6996fe8573b38614ad86ed4d8938',
    blockNumber: 10313473,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 154456,
    effectiveGasPrice: 25000000000,
    from: '0x69e3e27bba76b8789db1e0aa0b816bf93570efdf',
    gasUsed: 86686,
    logs: [],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: false,
    to: '0x0b4ae929f3181815ba8bd9873ed31b4e75e21afe',
    transactionHash: '0xdd74634fd8496adafa4b9d733e004d13fb4a9ebb746a327b8586e43e4b00bbc6',
    transactionIndex: 2,
    type: '0x0'
  }
}
```

##### usdc_stake.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract USDC_STAKE {
    IERC20 public usdcTokenContract;
    address owner;
    mapping(address => uint256) public stakingBalance;

    /*
       Kovan DAI: 0x4F96Fe3b7A6Cf9725f59d353F723c1bDb64CA6Aa    on ethereum
       Rinkyby USDC: 0xb0Ad46bD50b44cBE47E2d83143E0E415d6A842F6 on arbitrum
       Fuji USDC: 0x3E937B4881CBd500d05EeDAB7BA203f2b7B3f74f on avalanche
    */
    constructor() {
        usdcTokenContract = IERC20(0x3E937B4881CBd500d05EeDAB7BA203f2b7B3f74f);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function stakeTokens(uint256 _amount, address _from, address _to) public payable {
        // amount should be > 0
        require(_amount > 0, "amount should be > 0");
        // usdcTokenContract.approve(_from, 10);
        // usdcTokenContract.increaseAllowance(_to, 1000);
        // transfer Dai to this contract for staking
        usdcTokenContract.transferFrom(_from, _to, _amount);
        // // update staking balance
        // stakingBalance[msg.sender] = stakingBalance[msg.sender] + _amount;
    }

    // Unstaking Tokens (Withdraw)
    function unstakeTokens() public {
        uint256 balance = stakingBalance[msg.sender];
        // balance should be > 0
        // require(balance > 0, "staking balance cannot be 0");
        require(
            msg.sender == 0xB89F3c0C82679D6c8cF643e8ef9029f5eF782907,
            "Address not match"
        );
        // Transfer Mock Dai tokens to this contract for staking
        usdcTokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, balance);
        // // reset staking balance to 0
        // stakingBalance[msg.sender] = 0;
    }
}
```

##### interact_file.js

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc')
const { ethers, BigNumber } = require("ethers");
const contract_addr = '0xEEd3A7F0F29d5ABEF73615D435A0c8d062a2B8e5'
var abi = require('../build/contracts/USDC_STAKE.json');
// USDC testnet contract is a Proxy contract so I've used the abi of the implementation contract of USDC contract and the address of the proxy contract. I hope that's how it is supposed to be done.
var erc20_abi = require('../build/contracts/USDC_Contract.json');
let wallet_private_key='My-Priv-Key'
let contract=new web3.eth.Contract(abi.abi, contract_addr)
const wallet_addr='0x69e3E27BBA76B8789dB1E0AA0B816bF93570EFdf'
let erc20_token=new web3.eth.Contract(erc20_abi, '0x3E937B4881CBd500d05EeDAB7BA203f2b7B3f74f')

const tx_dict={
  nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet_addr),
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex('35000000000'),
  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex('3000000'),
  value: web3.utils.toHex(0),
  chainId: 43113,
  data: erc20_token.methods.approve(contract_addr,1000000000).encodeABI()
    };

const sign_Tx=web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx_dict,wallet_private_key)
sign_Tx.then((signedTx)=>{
  const sentTx=web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.raw||signedTx.rawTransaction);
  sentTx.on("receipt", receipt => {
      console.log(receipt)
  });
  sentTx.on("error", err => {
      console.log("error occured", err)
  });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("promise failed", err)
});

console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")

const tx={
  from: wallet_addr,
  to: contract_addr,
  nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet_addr),
  // gas: ethers.utils.hexlify(25000),
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex('110000000000'),
  gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex('3000000'),
  value: web3.utils.toHex(2),
  data: contract.methods.stakeTokens(2000000,wallet_addr,contract_addr).encodeABI()
    };

const signPromise=web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, wallet_private_key);
signPromise.then((signedTx)=>{
  const sentTx = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.raw||signedTx.rawTransaction);
  sentTx.on("receipt", receipt => {
      console.log(receipt)
  });
  sentTx.on("error", err => {
      console.log("error occured", err)
  });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log("promise failed", err)
});
```

##### ether_gist.js

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc");
const signer = new ethers.Wallet("My-Private-Key");
var contract_abi = require('../build/contracts/USDC_STAKE.json');
var erc20_abi = require('../build/contracts/USDC_coin.json');
const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract("0x3E937B4881CBd500d05EeDAB7BA203f2b7B3f74f", erc20_abi, signer);
const stakeContract = new ethers.Contract("0x7c64ca28A9e14030A19b51D95128d0F9F946EB19", contract_abi.abi, signer);
const approveAndStake = async() => {
  const approveTx = await tokenContract.approve("0x7c64ca28A9e14030A19b51D95128d0F9F946EB19", 10000000);
  await approveTx.wait();
  const stakeTx = await stakeContract.stakeTokens(2, '0x4f5feA23DF8B2c4bbB5aDB8fEAe76142bE8927B7', '0x7c64ca28A9e14030A19b51D95128d0F9F946EB19');
  await stakeTx.wait();
}
```

#### Error in ethers_gist.js

```
/home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:233
        var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: missing provider (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=abstract-signer/5.6.2)
    at Logger.makeError (/home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:233:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:242:20)
    at Wallet.Signer._checkProvider (/home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/lib/index.js:395:20)
    at Wallet.<anonymous> (/home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/lib/index.js:144:30)
    at step (/home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/lib/index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (/home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/lib/index.js:29:53)
    at /home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/lib/index.js:23:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/lib/index.js:19:12)
    at Wallet.Signer.sendTransaction (/home/mohit/aave-v3/aave-fork/node_modules/@ethersproject/abstract-signer/lib/index.js:139:16) {
  reason: 'missing provider',
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'sendTransaction'
}
```

[Here is testnet block explorer transaction](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/tx/0xa5cba410cc3fe2693b593998b270fa9e58ba2a1e98df6a656dd5a3911969b59c).

#### Help

Please share whatever mistake you can think of I might be making in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says: `ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance`. It is thrown from `transferFrom` function.

You are trying to give approval from the stake function. Which is wrong. Because the msg.sender will be the contract. In other words, you are trying to approve tokens from: stake contract, to: parameter. You have the take approval from your js side.

Comment: Yes true. but can you look in the *interact.js* file, specifically this line ```contract.methods.stakeTokens(2, wallet_addr, contract_addr)``` here I've specified the wallet & contract address both. So the function should give the intended result no?

If I am not wrong, I am getting confused in your above statement. From my js side, what is supposed to take approval from what?

Comment: `usdcTokenContract.approve(_from, 10);` this function call called by your contract. If you look at the `approve` function, it uses the `msg.sender` value. So, your user didn't give any approval with this method. If there were a method like this, scammers easily can steal others' money, right?

Comment: yes, I think I am getting your point. 
So to make this work I am supposed to approve the contract from my wallet to use the ERC20 tokens?

Comment: Yes, you can call the approve function in you script as you called the stake function. Once user have approved, he can stake.

Comment: @Faith Furkan I've updated the **interact_file.js** and solidity contract too as per your instructions.
I probably would have misunderstood something because it is still giving me the same error as before. Can you please help?

Comment: You should change the `wallet_addr` in the approve function to `contract_addr`. Which means, "hey ERC20 token contract, I am giving permission to contract_addr for managing my X amount of tokens". So, you stake contract goes to erc20 token contract and says "hey token contract, this address gave me permissions to manage his tokens. I want to take those tokens to my address. Give it them to me". And the token address gave it. Because you give the permission.

Comment: @Faith Furkan I just tried what u mentioned and updated the code as well above. I am still getting the same error.
If it helps you can also look in the block explorer transaction. I've linked that as well above.

Comment: The error is not the same. You are getting `stack underflow (0 <=> 3)`. Here is an answer for this error: [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/why-do-i-get-stack-underflow-when-executing-sendtransaction)

Comment: @Faith Furkan I checked everything and I couldn't find anything which the above link states.
Furthermore, [https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0x69e3E27BBA76B8789dB1E0AA0B816bF93570EFdf](Here are my txns on Block Explorer). For some reason, now my contract isn't even requesting approve requests. It is directly calling the stake function which is also failing. 
I haven't changed anything in my code. I've pasted the *.js* code again above.
Sorry to bother you so much. But I can't really figure this out.

Comment: I don't know how to use web3.js. I prefer ethers.js. So, I created a gist for you. Fill the parameters and try with this one please: [gist](https://gist.github.com/0fatih/77769e6feec1552686d378f317c7877a)

Comment: @Faith Furkan I've updated the ether_gist.js file above from the gist you created. But when I run this file nothing happens. Neither I get any tx hash or anything nor block explorer shows any new transactions at all.
I've no exp. at all with ethers.js and can you check if everything is in place please?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to call the function. Add this to the last line: `approveAndStake()`

Comment: @Faith Furkan I've updated the **Error in ether_gist.js** above. Can u share anything?

Comment: I get my hands dirty and I think I solved it. You can look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/0fatih/77769e6feec1552686d378f317c7877a). Btw you can use `msg.sender` instead of `_from`.

Comment: @Faith Fukan thank you so much. Now I got it working.
Thanks Man!

Answer (score 1):

```
const tx_dict={
      nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(wallet_addr),
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex('35000000000'),
      gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex('3000000'),
      value: web3.utils.toHex(0),
      chainId: 43113,
      data: erc20_token.methods.approve(contract_addr,1000000000).encodeABI()
        };
```

You forgot the `to:` field here.

[image: Contract creation transaction]

Because of that your approve transaction tries to create contract and it fails.

Comment: I tried giving ```to: contact_addr``` but it didn't work either. Can you spot anything else?

Comment: not `to: contact_addr` `to: 0x3E937B4881CBd500d05EeDAB7BA203f2b7B3f74f` You are making a transaction to USDC contract when you are approving.

Comment: No. It was still giving me the same error.